# Tiny artefact diamon in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I drew a flowchart with TikZ but, in a diamonded shaped decision block, a tiny diamond appears in the centre. How to get rid of it ?

[image: see screenshot]

```
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!10, 
    font=\small, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!10, 
    font=\small, text width=9em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) at (0,0) {set-up acquisition parameters};
        \node [block] (step1) at (0,-2) {bias the SiPM};
        \node [block] (step21) at (-3,-4) {read SiPM data and write in ROOT file};
        \node [block] (step22) at (3,-4) {read current from pico-ampermeter};
        \node [block] (step3) at (0,-6) {write header and current in ROOT file};
    \node [decision] (step4) at (0,-9) {is last bias voltage?};
        \node [block] at (-8,-6) (step41) {update value};
    \node [block] at (0,-12) (step42) {end};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (step1);
    \path [line] (step1) -- (step21);
    \path [line] (step1) -- (step22);
        \path [line] (step21) -- (step3);
        \path [line] (step22) -- (step3);
        \path [line] (step3) -- (step4);
    \path [line] (step4) -| node [near start, above] {no} (step41);
    \path [line] (step41) |- (step1);
    \path [line] (step4) -- node [midway, right] {yes}(step42);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My code, use above for the picture:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[frenchb,british]{babel}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[european,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
\usepackage[top=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage[english]{nomencl}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\tikzset{every picture/.style={scale=.8}}
\input{res/flowchart} %texfile containing my flowchart
\caption{Main program flowchart}
\label{fig:flowchart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide complete small document starting with ˙`\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` and all necessary packages and libraries which ones need in compilation of your code sniped.

Comment: The diamond is not from the code you posted.

Comment: @Ignasi I guess a bad interaction with the `circuitikz` package is the origin of the diamond. See similar question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319250/tikz-black-dot-diamond-in-center-of-all-diamond-shapes

Comment: I confirm @samcarter finding. If in my answer below you add `\usepackage{circuitikz}` this small diamond appear again! I test this with  `circuitikz` version 0.6 (2016/06/06). Unfortunately in above question wasn't any information about document preamble, so my answer below is based on guessing, as this is stated in it.

Comment: Hi, the bug is fixed at the latest git-version of circuitikz. Please use the latest git-version or change your local files according https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/commit/0bc542dc109f12af0158f9eb1fef944cecda815c

Comment: I download the latest git-version and replace files. The problem is solved ! Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your code, already indicate @ignasi in his comment, doesn't generate artifact as you show in image:

[image]

Of course, our test doesn't consider your actual document since you still not provide any information about it. So the test for above image I made with:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
<your code>
\end{document}
```

Off topic:
in preparation of test I made variation of your code, where the element of flowchart is positioned relatively and for used styles is used local settings (use of `\tikstyle` is depreciated). See, if it can be helpful for you:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=6mm and 8mm,
    base/.style = {draw, fill=blue!10, font=\small, align=flush center, outer sep=0pt},
decision/.style = {shape=diamond, base,
                   aspect=1.5, text width=4.5em, inner sep=1pt},
   block/.style = {shape=rectangle, base,
                   text width=9em, rounded corners, minimum height=3em},
    line/.style = {draw, -latex'}
                        ]
    % Place nodes
\node (init)   [block]    {set-up acquisition parameters};
\node (step1)  [block,below=of init]                {bias the SiPM};
\node (step21) [block,below  left=of step1.south]   {read SiPM data and write in ROOT file};
\node (step22) [block,below right=of step1.south]   {read current from pico-ampermeter};
\node (step3)  [block,below right=of step21.south]  {write header and current in ROOT file};
    \node (step4) [decision,below=of step3]         {is last bias voltage?};
\node (step41) [block,left=of step3 -| step21.west] {update value};
\node (step42) [block,below=of step4]               {end};
    % Draw edges
\draw[line] (init)   edge (step1)     (step1)  edge (step21)   (step1) edge (step22) 
            (step21) edge (step3)     (step22) edge (step3)    (step3)  to  (step4);
\draw[line] (step4) -| node [near start, above] {no} (step41);
\draw[line] (step41) |- (step1);
\draw[line] (step4) -- node [midway, right] {yes}(step42);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```