# TikZ - Black Dot/Diamond in Center of All Diamond Shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am making a flow chart and in the standalone TikZ file everything looks fine, but when I use `\input` into my thesis all of the diamonds have a small black diamond in the dead center of the shape. This happens with or without text in the node.  It's hard to include a working example due to the template of my thesis, but everything else looks the same.

Any idea what could be causing the small diamonds in the center?

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,arrows, positioning}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, top color=white, bottom color=red!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [draw, rectangle, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [draw, diamond, aspect=2, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (start) [startstop] {start};
\node (plf) [below=of start, process] {text \\ text};
\node (3) [below=of plf, decision] {text \\ $||$ \\ text};
\node (4) [below=of 3, process] {text $\pm$ 1};
\node (5) [below=of 4, process] {text \\ text};
\node (6) [below=of 5, process] {text \\ text};
\node (7) [below=of 6, process] {text};
\node (empty1) [right=of 3] {};
\node (9) [right=of empty1, decision] {text \\ text};
\node (10) [below=of 9, process] {text \\ text};
\node (stop) [below=of 10, startstop] {stop};

\node[coordinate] (12) [left=of 3] {};
\node[coordinate] (13) [right=of 9] {};

\draw [arrow] (start) -- (plf);
\draw [arrow] (plf) -- (3);
\draw [arrow] (3) -- node[anchor=west] {no} (4);
\draw [arrow] (4) -- (5);
\draw [arrow] (5) -- (6);
\draw [arrow] (6) -- (7);
\draw [arrow] (7) -| (12) --  (3);
\draw [arrow] (3) -- node[anchor=south] {yes} (9);
\draw [arrow] (9) --  node[anchor=west] {no}(10);
\draw [arrow] (9) -- node[anchor=south] {yes} (13) |- (stop);
\draw [arrow] (10) -- (stop);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Using your code (and changing `shapes.misc` to `shapes`) in an empty article does not show the problem. So without knowing the packages etc. of your thesis this can not be answered without guessing. Maybe some package redefines the diamond?

Comment: Here are some of the packages that are listed in my class file:

    \RequirePackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,patterns}
    \RequirePackage{pgfplots}
    \RequirePackage{circuitikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes}   

Would they make a difference?

Comment: OK, seems `\usepackage{circuitikz}` is the problem. Do you need it?

Comment: alternatively replace the diamond shape by a user defined one. How to do this, you can find at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301091/create-custom-symbol-diamond-rhombus-shape

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I am using circuitikz for other diagrams in the thesis.  I will check out the link to in creating the user defined shape and report back. Thank you!

Comment: Related but not helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318070/tiny-artefact-diamon-in-tikz. As apparently this problem does not happen on every computer I suspect this is related to the specific versions of the packages.

Comment: Please always post compilable code. This is particularly annoying to work with since it muddles preamble fragments and document body.

Comment: This is really a bug in `circuitikz`. It ought not declare a shape with the same name as one defined by `shapes.geometric` (***not*** `shapes.misc`, by the way - another reason to post a complete example so you can check it). Has it been reported? The other thing it could do is just change the definition locally inside its own environment.

Comment: According the change log, the diamond shape was introduced in v0.6 (June 2016).

Comment: @cfr I just reported it at https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/45

Comment: Hi, the bug is fixed at the latest git-version of circuitikz.  Please use the latest git-version or change your local files according https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/commit/0bc542dc109f12af0158f9eb1fef944cecda815c

Comment: @sistlind thanks!  I made the changes, no issues now :)

Answer (score 2):

The cause of your problem is discovered and described in above comments of *samcarter* and *cfr* (thanks to both!). As temporary solution of this problem can be:

1. as suggested *cfr* in her comment
2. with existing MWE generate pdf file and than it include in your document as image: `\includegraphics{<flowchart name>}`
3. instead `diamond` use different shape, for example `signal` which has some similarity with it

For last possibility the MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}% <-- makes trouble before
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, chains, quotes, positioning, 
                shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 6mm and 12mm,
      start chain = going below,% <-- new
      base/.style = {draw, minimum width=4.5em, align=flush center, outer sep=0pt,
                     on chain},% <-- new
  decision/.style = {shape=signal, base,% <-- new, replace diamond
                     signal to=west and east,
                     top color=white, bottom color=green!30},
   process/.style = {shape=rectangle, base,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!30},
 startstop/.style = {shape=rectangle, base,
                     rounded corners,
                     top color=white, bottom color=red!30},
     arrow/.style = {thick, -stealth},
every join/.style = {arrow}
                        ]
% left column 
\node (start)   [startstop] {start};
\node (plf)     [process,join]   {text \\ text};
\node (3)       [decision,join]  {text \\ $||$ \\ text};
\node (4)       [process]   {text $\pm$ 1};
\node (5)       [process,join]   {text \\ text};
\node (6)       [process,join]   {text \\ text};
\node (7)       [process,join]   {text};
% right column
\node (8)       [decision,right=of 3] {text \\ text};
\node (9)       [process]        {text \\ text};
\node (stop)    [startstop,join] {stop};
% auxiliary coordinates
\coordinate[left =of 3.west] (10);
\coordinate[right=of 8.east] (11);
% connection lines
\draw [arrow]   (3) edge ["no"]   (4) 
                (3) edge ["yes"]  (8)
                (8) edge ["no"]   (9)
                (8)  to  ["yes"]  (11) |- (stop);
\draw [arrow]   (7) -| (10) -- (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

In above MWE I also employ TikZ libraries `chains` and `quotes` and by their help made code more concise. I also move flowchart elements styles definitions to option of TikZ picture. Iz can be defined elsewhere as `\tikzset{...}` instead of obsolete `tikzstyle`. Obtained image with this code is below.

[image]