# Circuitikz and tikzlibrary shapes.geometric not works properly together.

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

In my tex documment, I use circuitikz and tikz libraries together. When I try to draw decision block for flowchart, I found annoying behavior. Miktex puts in center of the Diamond shape some character, that should not be there at all (see figure below). If I comment `circuitikz` library, everything si OK, but it is not solution for my documment.

[image]

**NWME:**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [draw, diamond, aspect=2] {hello};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319250/tikz-black-dot-diamond-in-center-of-all-diamond-shapes#comment781222_319250

Comment: Samcarter solution is based on using other shape (Signal). I need shape diamond. In the answer is written that is a temporary solution! I do not agree that my  question was considered as a duplicate.

Comment: Have you tried to use the updated package from github, as explained in the comment I linked to? If this does not work for other shapes, reopen the bug report at https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/45

Comment: today i released a new version of circuitikz containing the fix, just update your installation